# The number of boolean functions with given decision tree complexity

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

How many boolean function with $n$ variables with decision tree complexity $k$?

By decision tree complexity of a function $f$ I mean the smallest depth among all deterministic decision trees that computes  $f$.

Approximation results, bounds,  efficient algorithms to find the value are interested for me.

I know only the following simple fact: if  boolean function $f$ with $n$ variables has complexity less than $n$ then relative Hamming distance between $f$ and XOR is $\frac{1}{2}$. (This implies an upper bound for the number of such functions.)

Comment: Well, it's at most $(2n)^{2^k}$. Or slightly better, $n(n-1)^2(n-2)^4\cdots(n-k+1)^{2^{k-1}}2^{2^k}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Could you please explain?

Comment: Just count the number of decision trees of depth $k$. You may assume that it’s the perfect binary tree of the given depth. There are $2^k-1$ inner nodes, hence $n^{2^k-1}$ choices for the query variables, and for each of the $2^k$ leaves, you have two choices for the output value. For the second bound, you may assume that no variable is queried twice along the same path, reducing the number of possibilities for the query variables at each level.

Comment: A similar argument which gives the second bound but allows any improvement to propagate is to say that if $B(n, k)$ counts the number of distinct Boolean functions on $n$ variables with decision tree complexity $k$ then $B(n, k) \le n B(n-1, k-1)^2$: choose the variable for the first decision from the $n$ available and then remove it from consideration.

Comment: One improvement is to argue by induction that if a variable $x$ is queried on every path from the root to a leaf then there is a rearranged tree of the same height which puts $x$ at the root. Then if you have $m$ variables which are queried on every path, that gives a (not tight in general) lower bound of $m!$ on the size of the equivalence class of trees which are equivalent if they represent the same function. I haven't tried to calculate better bounds on $B(n, k)$ using this argument.

Comment: Another improvement is to observe that if the two subtrees of the root are equal then the root is unnecessary, so the function has complexity lower than the height of the tree. This gives $B(n, k) \le n B(n-1, k-1) (B(n-1, k-1) - 1)$.